# Error 'source not found' cuando voy a realizar debug en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

He intentado de muchas formas hacer debugging para un archivo jsp, pero siempre me sigue saliendo 'source not found', copié los archivos del proyecto en el build path. Aqui está uno de mis intentos por solucionar el problema (la solución normal)

[image: img 1]

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer debug de tus scriptlets?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174550/eclipse-java-debugging-source-not-found alli encontraras la respuesta.